# python : intersection geometrical objects in 3D space

Tags: python, math, geometry, gekko

**Definition of the problem**

I am trying to calculate the points of intersection of geometrical objects, such as two planes and a sphere, in python.
Let's consider for example these three objects: 
[image: 1] 
[image: 2] 
[image: 3]

This system gives two solutions: 
 
[image: 4] 
 
[image: 5]

I would like to know if there is a python library that can help develop a solver to calculate these intersections. I am looking for something working as Wolfram alpha, where we can input three equations and it returns all the possible solutions when there's finite number of solutions for simplicity.

**What I tried**

I tried with SymPy, but it returns `[]`:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')
solve(z, x, x**2 + y**2 + z**2 -1)
```

I then tried with `scipy`:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def f(x):
    y = np.zeros(3)
    y[2] = x[2]
    y[0] = x[0]
    y[1] = x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2+  x[2] ** 2  - 1
    return y


x0 = np.array([10, 10, 10])
solution = fsolve(f, x0)
print(solution[0],solution[1],solution[2])
```

but it only returns one of the two solutions: 
`6.79746218330325e-28 1.0000000000000002 -2.3528179942097343e-35`

I also tried with `gekko`, and stil it only returns one possible solution (which depends on the initial guess):

```
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(value = 1)
y = m.Var(value = 1)
z = m.Var(value = 1)
m.Equation(x == 0)
m.Equation(z == 0)
m.Equation(x**2 + y**2+z**2 ==1)
m.solve()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with `sympy`. Apparently it's one of the only (if not only) libraries that allow finding analytical solutions, and returns more than just one solution. Also, we don't need to pass guesses as initial variables. In my question, there was an error in the example I posted with sympy. This is how I solved the system:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
import sympy as sp

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')

sp.solve([z , x, (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - 1],  x,y,z)
```

*Result: [0,-1,0], [0,1,0]*

Answer (score 0):

fsolve from scipy, and all other functions that I personally know of that will accept any form of input function, will return one value.
One workaround if you have an idea where the other solution is would be to give an x0 value that is closer to the second solution with a second call to fsolve (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).

If you alternatively know what range you want to try and find solutions in, the easiest way is to make an array that you then check to see where the value changes sign (this would be doing it from scratch)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know the range, but that means I would have to discretize the space which is something I don't want to do. I am looking for a general solution, like Wolfram alpha does returning the exact solutions.

Comment: Odds are that mathematica or matlab (the free bit that mathematica builds on) would be a better go to for that particular application then. Not sure how to use python to do it without discretization